# Parse Json Response and fll arraylist

Tags: android, json, web-services, parsing, arraylist

- I am able to get json response
- But i dont know how to fetch data inside reponse and how to get particular filed and fill arraylist
- What i have done is :

  ```
     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

          fruit = preferenceHelper.getWalkerfruit();
          flower = preferenceHelper.getWalkerflower();
          try {

              // Building Parameters
              params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fruit", lfruit));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flower", flower));

              Log.d("Parameters", params.toString());


              Log.d("request!", "starting");

              // getting user details by making HTTP request
              JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(FLOWER_SERVICE, "POST", params);

              // check your log for json response
              Log.d("attempt", json.toString());

             JSONObject jsonObject = userData.getJSONObject(0);

              JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
              String success = json.optString("status");
              String msgd = json.getString("message");
              String str_value = json.getString("id");
              Log.d("id", str_value);
              arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
              for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
               {
                  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  Log.d("oasdasdbj", obj.toString());

                  String str_value = obj.getString("id");
                  Log.d("alert_idasdas", str_value);
                  id = obj.getString(Constants.Params.ID);

                  map.put("id", str_value);
                  Log.d("map", map.toString());
                  arraylist1.add(map);

              }
                Log.d("response", " " + msgd);

              if (success.equals("false")) {
                  Log.d("Failure!", json.toString());
                  finish();
                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

              } else if (success.equals("true")) {
                  Log.d("Successful!", json.toString());

                  }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

          }
          return null;
      }
  ```

Json response :

```
{"status":true,"message":"Successfully","Data":[{"id":"92","name":"","abcd":"dfgfddg","adfffwe":"asdsad"}]}
```

Comment: what you want to do with this Response tell me in brief

Comment: Your response is stored inside '{}' right, which is a json object, you need to read Data, which is a json array. You can do like jsonObject.getJsonArray("Data"); and store it in a jsonArray variable, then process accordingly. Check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: i want id from json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonResponse contains what you have got from server.

```
JSONArray array= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Data");
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String id= obj.getString("Id");
}
```

Change datatype of id according to your need. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not test the code, this may not be exact solution, can you debug and see what is coming inside JSONArray array variable and modify code accordingly. I don't have android setup right now on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

**It's invalid `JSON`,It's may be a copying issue But As I validate this is the valid one**

```
{"status":true,"message":"Successfully","Data":[{"id":"92","name":"","abcd":"dfgfddg","adfffwe":"asdsad"}]}
```

**To fetch The data inside `Data` Object of this JSON you can do**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = userData.getJSONObject(0);
jsonObject.getJsonArray("Data").getJsonObject(0).getString("abcd") //To fetch the value of abcd inside Data Object
jsonObject.getJsonArray("Data").getJsonObject(0).getString("id") //To fetch the value of abcd inside Data Object
```

Same like this..

Answer (score 2):

```
//Editing AlokGupta Code:
JSONArray array= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Data");
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String id= obj.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: AlokGupta likes this. :p Thanks @Amit